# Passing data to OSGI Bundles

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I don't know how far the discussion in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434664/accessing-command-line-arguments-from-osgi-bundle) is still relevant, but I'm not able to read system properties from a Felix `BundleActivator`.

Is this working for anybody out there? Or can somebody help me figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

Try to get system property with [`BundleContext.getProperty(String key)`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29)