# Shutdown an OSGi container after some code has been executed (to create a command-line tool)

Tags: java, command-line, osgi, equinox, bnd

I would like to create a command-line tool that starts an OSGi framework, in order to reuse code that is relying on OSGi.

In the answer [accessing command-line arguments from OSGi bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13641018/91497), I got how I can read the command line arguments:

```java
@Component
public class Example {

    String[] args;

    @Activate
    void activate() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println(args.length + " args:");
        for (String s : args) {
            System.out.println(" - " + s);
        }
    }

    @Reference(target = "(launcher.arguments=*)")
    void args(Object object, Map<String, Object> map) {
        if (map.containsKey("launcher.arguments")) {
            args = (String[]) map.get("launcher.arguments");
        } else {
            args = new String[] {};
        }
    }
}
```

But now when I run the assembled jar (`bnd-export-maven-plugin`) like this:

```
java -jar <path-to>/application.jar lorem ipsum
```

I get the expected output, but the application does not terminate.

After having read [4.2.6 Stopping a Framework](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.lifecycle.html#framework.lifecycle.stopping), I was thinking that I need to call `stop()` on the system bundle. I have tried to change my code to:

```java
@Activate
void activate(BundleContext bundleContext) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    System.out.println(args.length + " args:");
    for (String s : args) {
        System.out.println(" - " + s);
    }
    try {
        bundleContext.getBundle().stop();
    } catch (BundleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it does not seems to work like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the system bundle to stop you must do (notice the 0):

```
 bundleContext.getBundle(0).stop();
```

To do this hyper correctly, you should do this in another thread.

```
@Component
public class ServiceComponent {

    @Activate
    void activate(BundleContext c) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync( ()-> {
            try {
                c.getBundle(0).stop();
            } catch (BundleException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } );        
    }
}
```

This is, of course, a suicide component ...

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! In my eyes the "suicide" aspect is perfectly fine for a CLI tool, logic is performed before the app is killed.